# Getting value from selected Bootstrap dropdown option

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning development and what I want is a bootstrap dropdown with 3 backgroun image options and then to pass the selected option change the background.  At the moment I can't find how to even get the value of the selected option.  I've searched high and low to find how to get the value of the selected option and then use it but I can't find anything.  Even the bootstrap documentation is vague.

So far the dropdown renders ok...

```
<div class="dropdown open">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Background
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Image 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Image 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Image 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

but then I get stuck...

```
$('#dropdownMenuButton').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
  // get selected option and change background
})
```

I can change the background but I just can't get the value of the selected option.

I can't believe it is so difficult so I'm obviously missing something.  Please can anyone help?

Thanks,

LB

Comment: Are you trying to get the text value or the href value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return the text value of the item clicked on. Beware that this is not a `select` element though.

```
$('.dropdown-item').click(function() {
  console.log( $(this).text() );
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  Worked like a charm.  Can't think where I went wrong, it's so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the "hidden.bs.dropdown" event you may listen for the click event on the "dropdown-item":

```js
$('#dropdownMenuButton + [aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"] a').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // get selected option and change background
  var ele = this;
  console.log(ele.textContent);
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown open">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Background
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Image 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Image 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Image 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just showing another approach for whatever reason:

```
<div id="mydd" class="dropdown open">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Background
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Image 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Image 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Image 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Then:

```
$('#mydd').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
        var selected = $('.dropdown-item:active');
        // get properties from selected and use
 ...etc...
});
```